# Placing CTA in left or right side?

Tags: website-design, cta

Most websites will have the main form ( book a hotel, a flight etc. ) placed either on the center of the page or on the left side. I cannot recall any that has it placed on the right side.

The website I am redesigning has this form on the right side and while I find it logical to have it sit on the left side, I am looking for some information regarding this so I can argument my decision rather than base it on intuition.

The other issue is that present users might be adjusted to how the page is currently made but we are looking to also find new users ...

Ex:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A research conducted by the [Nielsen Norman Group in 2017](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/horizontal-attention-leans-left/), used eye-tracking to examine where do people focus their attention most frequently when carrying out web-based tasks on a 1920×1080 monitor. There were more than 120 participants and their findings showed that 80% fixated on the left half of the screen.

Those findings were in agreement with a [similar study of theirs done in 2010](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/horizontal-attention-original-research/) for a 1024×768 monitor.

Keep in mind the above relates to the reading patterns in the western world, in which case aim for the most important content that you want your users to take action on to be located on the left half of your website, and secondary or non-priority content (e.g. the image) on the right.

[image]
This figure was reproduced from the [Nielsen Norman Group study in 2017.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/horizontal-attention-leans-left/)

Comment: This is where the Gutenberg Diagram comes into action. While people focus on the left side to gather information, the CTA would purely disappear or be "over-readed" within all the information. CTA's are usually already prominently styled with a striking color and position. If you check even closer you can see that the F-Pattern proves, that especially CTA on the right is as prominent as content on the left. (https://medium.com/@lineindesign/be-a-designer-who-can-also-help-with-writing-copy-2f4ea02a5646).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the so called "Gutenberg Diagram"
https://medium.com/user-experience-3/the-gutenberg-diagram-in-web-design-e5347c172627

Short answer: Bottom-Right of your landing/hero

Comment: I would tend to agree with you on this, bottom right. Looking at the two examples, and in particular the type of image being used (heavy drop-shadow), when the call to action is on the left it is overshadowed (pardon the pun) by the image (due to the drop-shadow). Whereas with the CTA on the right it's definitely easier for the eye to be attracted to.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running an A B test with your users on the site. The only difference being the placement of the form. The data should then help to inform the placement.